# How to disable respawn for terminal?

Tags: linux, tty, init

In old 5.3 rhel, we used to define the number of terminals and their respawn settings in 
`/etc/inittab` file as below.

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty2
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty3
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty4 ....etc for 12 terminals
```

In new RHEL 6.4, we need to define the terminals in `/etc/sysconfig/init` file as below

```
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-9] /dev/tty10 /dev/tty11 /dev/tty12"
```

Now, how can I turn off the respawn property for any terminal.. say tty5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is more involved than just editing the `/etc/inittab` now. I found 2 examples that were helpful:

- [Replacing TTY with a script in CentOS 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/323289/replacing-tty-with-a-script-in-centos-6)
- [RHEL 6 Tech Notes Deployment](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_technical_notes/rhel_6_technotes_deployment.html)

The gist, modify this file: `/etc/init/start-ttys.conf`:

```
script
    . /etc/sysconfig/init
    for tty in $(echo $ACTIVE_CONSOLES) ; do
          [ "$RUNLEVEL" = "5" -a "$tty" = "$X_TTY" ] && continue
            if [ "$tty" == "/dev/tty5" ]; then
                    initctl start no_respawn_tty  TTY=$tty
                    continue
            fi
            initctl start tty TTY=$tty
    done
end script
```

Then create the corresponding script, `/etc/init/no_respawn_tty.conf`:

```
# tty - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on the specified device.

stop on runlevel [S016]

instance $TTY
exec /sbin/mingetty $TTY
usage 'tty TTY=/dev/ttyX  - where X is console id'
```

The changes should be seen immediately, I don't think you need to restart anything.